# Problem after installing node.js on Debian Lenny

Tags: installation, debian

I managed to install node.js successfully on my machine but when invoking

```
make test
```

I get an error message:

```
python tools/test.py --mode=release simple
=== release test-net-pingpong ===                               
Path: simple/test-net-pingpong
server listening on 20989 localhost
server listening on 20988 undefined
Error: EAFNOSUPPORT, Address family not supported by protocol
    at net:1041:19
    at dns:105:7
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:48:25)
    at node.js:176:9
```

I found out that EAFNOSUPPORT means that the OS does not support a particular protocol and a program tries to use it. So from what I can deduce my Debian does not have support for dns?

Any help is appreciated!